# php mysql + seperate between each type of search

Tags: php, mysql, jquery, select

I am creating a search form where user can select between three types of search by name or by specialization or by location  but the problem is that the system only search by name

How can I disable or separate between these 3 types of search?

This is the code: until now I did the search by ame  and search by specialization but it did not get success

Can anyone help me?

**search.php**:

```
<?php
session_start();
if($_SESSION['login'] != 'true'){
        header("location:index.php");
    }


   $login = ($_SESSION['login']);
   $userid = ($_SESSION['user_id']);
   $login_user = ($_SESSION['username']);
   $fname = ($_SESSION['first_name']);
   $lname = ($_SESSION['last_name']);
   $sessionaddres =($_SESSION['address']);


require_once('for members/scripts/connect.php'); 

// function for selecting names
function nameQuery(){

  $nameData = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user") or die("could select database");

  while($record = mysql_fetch_array($nameData)){

     echo'<option value="' . $record['user_name'] .  '">' . $record['user_name'] . '</option>';
  }
}

// function for select by specialization

function specializationQuery(){

$specData = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM specialization");

  while($recordJob = mysql_fetch_array($specData)){

     echo'<option value="' . $recordJob['specialization_id'] .  '">' . $recordJob['specialization_name'] . '</option>';

  }
}

if(isset($_POST['search']))
{
    $Sgov = $_POST['governorate'];
    @$Sdist = $_POST['district'];
    @$Svillage = $_POST['village'];

    // query  search by name
    if(isset($_POST['name']))
    {
        $Sname =$_POST['name'];
    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT first_name, last_name, profile_pic FROM user WHERE user_name ='$Sname'")or die(mysql_error());

    if($sql)
    {
     while($getrow = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
     {
        $firstname = $getrow['first_name'];
        $lastname = $getrow['last_name'];
        $profilepic = $getrow['profile_pic'];

        if($profilepic == "") 
         {
             $profile_pic = "images/default_img.jpg";
         }
         else
         {
             $profile_pic = "userdata/profile_pics/".$profilepic;
         }

         echo "<ul>
          <li>
           ".$firstname. " ".$lastname ."
          </li>
          <li>
           <img style='width:80px' src='".$profile_pic . "'>
          </li>
         </ul>";
     }
   }
   else
   {
       echo "their was no result!!!!";
   }
  }
}

// search by specialization

if(isset($_POST['specialization']))
{
    $Sspec = $_POST['specialization'];
    $sql = mysql_query(" SELECT first_name, last_name, profile_pic FROM user WHERE specialization = '$Sspec'")or die(mysql_error());

    if($sql)
    {
      while($getrow = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
      {
        $firstname = $getrow['first_name'];
        $lastname = $getrow['last_name'];
        $profilepic = $getrow['profile_pic'];

        if($profilepic == "") 
         {
             $profile_pic = "images/default_img.jpg";
         }
         else
         {
             $profile_pic = "userdata/profile_pics/".$profilepic;
         }

         echo "<ul>
          <li>
           ".$firstname. " ".$lastname ."
          </li>
          <li>
           <img style='width:80px' src='".$profile_pic . "'>
          </li>
         </ul>";
     }
   }
   else
   {
       echo "their was no result!!!!";
   }
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>search page</title>
<link href="style/stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type = "text/javascript" src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

 $(document).ready(function(){
                $("select#district").attr("disabled","disabled");
                $("select#village").attr("disabled","disabled");
                $("select#governorate").change(function(){
                $("select#district").attr("disabled","disabled");
                $("select#district").html("<option>wait...</option>");
                var id = $("select#governorate option:selected").attr('value');
                $.post("select_district.php", {id:id}, function(data){
                    $("select#district").removeAttr("disabled");
                    $("select#district").html(data);
                });
            });
            $("select#district").change(function(){ 
            id = $(this).val(); 
            $("select#village").attr("disabled","disabled");
            $("select#village").html("<option>wait...</option>");
            $.post("select_village.php", {id:id}, function(data){


            $("select#village").removeAttr("disabled");
            $("select#village").html(data);
         });
        });
            $("form#registerform").submit(function(){
                var cat = $("select#governorate option:selected").attr('value');
                var type = $("select#district option:selected").attr('value');
                var village = $("select#village option:selected").attr('value');

            });
    });


</script>
</head>


<body>
<div class="container">
<!--<?php require_once('header.php'); ?>-->
<br />
<br />
<br />
<br />

  <!-- <?php require_once('leftsideBar2.php'); ?>-->


   <div id="search-title">Search section</div>
    <div id="search-form">
    <?php include "select.class.php"; ?>
        <form action="search.php" method="post">

         Search By Name:<br />
         <select name="name" >
            <?php nameQuery(); ?>
             <option id="0">-- select By UserName --</option>
             </select>
           <br/><br/>
           Search By Governorate:<br />

        <select id="governorate" name = 'governorate'>
                <?php echo $opt->ShowGovernorate(); ?>
                </select>
           <br /><br/>
           Search by District:<br />

      <select id="district" name="district">
                    <option value="0">choose...</option>
                </select>

           <br /><br/>
           Search by Cities:<br />
           <select id="village" name="village">
                    <option value="0">choose...</option>
                </select>
           <br /><br/>
           Search By Specialization:<br />
           <select name="specialization">
             <option id="0" disabled="disabled">-- select Job --</option>

          <?php specializationQuery(); ?>
          </select>
          <input type="submit" name="search" value="Search"  />
        </form>

    </div>
</div>
<?php require_once('footer.php'); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This condition will always true when you submit your form

```
if(isset($_POST['search']))
```

Instead of this you should have condition like this

```
if(isset($_POST['name'])) {
   //your code
}

if(isset($_POST['specialization'])) {
   //your code
}

if(isset($_POST['governorate'])) {
   //your code
}
etc.....
```